# Failed to start myunit service in Centos 7

Tags: centos, gradle, systemd

Здравствуйте!
Я столкнулся с задачей связанной с написанием unit'a systemd в Centos 7. 
сервис должен при старте системы запускать веб приложение. 
Был написан такой юнит

```
[Unit]
DefaultDependencies=no
Description=eureka-service

[Service]
Type=forking
WorkingDirectory=/usr/crm/develop/crm-backend/crm-backend
ExecStart=/usr/crm/develop/crm-backend/crm-backend && gradle eureka-service:bootRun & echo $! >> eureka.pid
PIDFile=/usr/crm/develop/crm-backend/eureka.pid

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Пишу следующие команды

```
systemctl enable eureka
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl -l status eureka
```

В консоль выводится

```
eureka.service - eureka-service 
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/eureka.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled) 
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2016-07-15 11:42:23 SAMT; 7min ago 
Process: 2218 ExecStart=/usr/crm/develop/crm-backend/crm-backend && gradle eureka-service:bootRun & echo $! >> eureka.pid (code=exited, status=203/EXEC) 
Starting eureka-service... 
eureka.service: control process exited, code=exited status=203 
Failed to start eureka-service. 
Unit eureka.service entered failed state. 
eureka.service failed.
```

используется centos 7

Comment: */usr/crm/develop/crm-backend/crm-backend* — вы определитесь, каталог это или исполняемый файл.

Comment: _/usr/crm/develop/crm-backend/crm-backend_ это каталог,
_gradle eureka-service:bootRun & echo $! >> eureka.pid_ это команда, которая выполняется в этом каталоге

Comment: если это каталог, зачем же вы пытаетесь его «выполнить»?

Comment: я понял вас,  исправил этот момент.
Сейчас команда выглядит следующим образом
`gradle -q -p /usr/crm/develop/crm-backend/crm-backend eureka-service:bootRun & echo $! >> eureka.pid`

Comment: @Dmity `echo $! >> eureka.pid` — в таком варианте pid будет **добавлен** в файл. вероятно, файл надо перезаписать: `echo $! > eureka.pid`